# Why isn't this render format limiting requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I allow a controller method `#new` to render its corresponding view template implicitly/by default, when I request `/users/password/new`, I see the corresponding template, and when I request `/users/password/new.zip`, it 404s. This is what I want.

However, because I need to pass a variable to the template, I'm calling `render` explicitly and passing `locals`, and `formats: :html` as well, in order to solve the problem I'm about to describe. So it looks something like:

`render :new, locals: { myvar: someval }, formats: :html` (basically that)

In this case, the first path renders the template as expected, but requesting `/users/password/new.zip` renders the new template instead of returning a 404. In other words, it's matching on `new` and ignoring the extension `.zip`, which I do not want to match this route.

You may notice that this is a Devise standard path, and the code has nothing else in routes or configuration (as far as I know) that should cause this behavior.

I've tried a number of different variations of this, and done the usual searching, but have not been able to solve this problem.

How can I call render such that I'm able to render the `new` template, pass it `locals` as explained, *and* restrict the response to only `:html`/default types?

So:

- `/users/password/new` should succeed, and
- `/users/password/new.zip`, or any other type besides HTML, should 404

As explained, the latter currently render's Devise's reset password screen (which lives at this path).

Thanks.

Comment: where are you calling this render statement from? Can you provide a bit more context? `render` will just discard your `formats` option because it is not routing it is `rendering`

Comment: I would recommend using an instance variable `@my_var = some_val` rather than trying to pass a local. This will avoid the need to call render explicitly and along with the format block referenced below will restrict access.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :new, locals: { myvar: someval }, formats: :html }
end
```

But I can't say I've tested what you are testing. But it should only respond to html. Also the last `formats: :html` may be unnecessary.